# How to add the multiple sum statement in sql if value has zero it returns total amount to zero how to add in multiple sum statement

Tags: sql-server

(sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi'  and  DIVISION='Dammam Central'  and STATUS is null  then  (current_salary)   end))-(sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and DIVISION='Dammam Central'  and internal_transfer_from in ('Dammam Central','Dammam East','Jeddah SMPT','Jubail','hadeed MTO','Hadeed FPH','IBN Rushd')  then (current_salary) end))+((sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and internal_transfer_from='Dammam Central' then (current_salary) end))) as Dammam_Central,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
isnull((sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and DIVISION='Dammam Central' and STATUS is null then (current_salary) end)),0)-
isnull((sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and DIVISION='Dammam Central' and internal_transfer_from in ('Dammam Central','Dammam East','Jeddah SMPT','Jubail','hadeed MTO','Hadeed FPH','IBN Rushd') then (current_salary) end)),0)+
isnull(((sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and internal_transfer_from='Dammam Central' then (current_salary) end))),0) as Dammam_Central,
```

**Note :** FYI refer [Handling Nulls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/handling-null-values)

Answer (score 0):

use **coalesce**(fieldname,0) = casesum(fieldnames) = 0  then sum() else sum() end

Sample above

```
COALESCE(sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and DIVISION='Dammam Central' and STATUS is null then (current_salary) end)),0)- COALESCE(sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and DIVISION='Dammam Central' and internal_transfer_from in ('Dammam Central','Dammam East','Jeddah SMPT','Jubail','hadeed MTO','Hadeed FPH','IBN Rushd') then (current_salary) end)),0)+(COALESCE(sum (case when NATIONALITY != 'Saudi' and internal_transfer_from='Dammam Central' then (current_salary) end)),0) as Dammam_Central
```

Comment: wat does it mean how to use the above one